# Magus question: Combining spell strike and spell combat

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magus

I was hoping yall could answer a specific question related to my character. Unfortunately, I don't have the reputation points to link more than 2 of my abilities. Apologies!

I play a level 9 Magus with a single Mythic Tier and as I gain more attacks through my BAB progression and with abilities like Speed for my weapon and the Sudden Attack Mythic ability - I start to lose focus with how the Spell Combat and Spellstrike work together in concert during a full attack round and it's creating friction between myself and the GM.

To make things simple, the following scenario (and I'll repeat it a couple times) involves my magus being directly adjacent to a foe.

Currently my BAB is +6/1, so each round I get two melee attacks with my scimitar. If I enhance my scimitar with Speed (via [Arcane Pool](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.d20pfsrd.com%2Fclasses%2Fbase-classes%2Fmagus&ei=iPTPU7a1JYS1yATtnICICQ&usg=AFQjCNHU-WN_OFUWLpjWhcO50-YjA775ZQ) with the [Speed](http://paizo.com/prd/magicitems/weapons.html) enhancement)
 , it breaks down to +6/1/6 as I get the additional attack at my highest attack bonus. If I use a Mythic pool point (using Sudden Attack), I can then perform an additional attack, suddenly using a swift action, at my highest BAB. Giving me a total of 4 standard attacks of +6/1/6/6 (if I've read things correctly.)

Now using Spell Combat I must apply a -2 to all my melee attacks (including my Spellstrike) if I'm casting a spell in my off hand (Vampiric Touch) and attacking with my scimitar.

So let's say I'm directly adjacent to my foe; can I (using Spell Combat) attack first w/ Vampiric Touch in my OFF-hand, then attack using Spellstrike with my MAIN hand cast Shocking Grasp through the scimitar at +6 (-2) (plus mods, etc) and then the rest of my melee attacks at +1 (-2), then +6 (-2) (hasted), then as a swift action activating my Mythic pool Sudden Attack +6 (-2)?  This would be a total of 2 touch spells and 4 melee attacks in a Full-Round Action.

My GM seems to think I'm limited to a single spell per round. What do you think? I really appreciate your consideration and help with this complicated class question!

Comment: What ability and combination of actions is allowing you to cast two spells in one round?

Comment: Spellstrike and Spell Combat http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus#TOC-Spell-Combat-Ex-
One ability allows me to cast a spell in my off hand and make all of my melee attacks at a -2. The other ability (spell strike) allows me to cast a spell through my weapon as a free action.

Comment: It states the following under the Spellstrike heading on the [Magus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus#TOC-Spell-Combat-Ex-) page. "If the magus makes this attack in concert with spell combat, this melee attack takes all the penalties accrued by spell combat melee attacks."

Comment: As a sidenote (just to make sure you haven't missed it): You can't activate your arcane pool and and sudden attack in the same round as both are swift actions.

Comment: I would like to point out that speed gives you the extra attack like 6/6/1, not 6/1/6. You ALWAYS take your attacks from highest to lowest.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your GM is correct. Spellstrike doesn't give you a free cast, what it allows you to do is turn your melee touch attack from casting a spell into a normal attack, allowing you to deal your weapon damage in addition to the spell.

> At 2nd level, whenever a magus casts a spell with a range of “touch” from the magus spell list, he can deliver the spell through any weapon he is wielding as part of a melee attack. Instead of the free melee touch attack normally allowed to deliver the spell, a magus can make one free melee attack with his weapon (at his highest base attack bonus) as part of casting this spell.

[Spellstrike Description on d20pfsrd](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus#TOC-Spell-Combat-Ex-).

So assuming I've got all my rules straight (someone please double check me on this) you would get a total of 5 melee attacks (4, 4, -1, 4, 4) plus one spell touch affect if at least one of those melee attacks hit. You use spell combat to cast a melee touch attack spell, which spellstrike turns into melee attack at highest BAB. You get your normal attacks, and your attacks from Speed and Sudden Attack. Since [missing doesn't cost you your touch attack charge](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/39395/if-a-touch-spell-misses-can-it-be-retried-until-it-hits), you can keep trying to deliver your spell with each attack.

As Louis Huppenbauer pointed out, both using the Arcane Pool and Sudden Attack are swift actions, so making 5 melee attacks relies upon you having applied Speed in a previous round (it has a duration of 1 minute).