# Can a feat "interupt" another feat?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, opportunity-attack

Can a feat stop another feat, while said first feat is in effect?
For example: Would a character with the feat [Deflect Attack](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Deflect_Attack_(3.5e_Feat)) (homebrew feat) be able to use the feat Evasive Reflexes

> When an opponent gives you a chance to make an attack of opportunity, you can instead immediately take a 5-foot step.

… to get an 5-foot step from Deflect Attack?
I belive that it can't, my friend belives that it can.

As a broader more general question: Can feats change other feats and apply the new effect before the full effect of the first feat comes into effect?

Comment: @tzxAzrael 
The solution to 1 AoO per turn is solved by combat expertise. 
The solution to reach would be [A character with a reach weapon also has the feat Improved Unarmed Strike; does he threaten all squares within 10' simultaneously?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/56565/a-character-with-a-reach-weapon-also-has-the-feat-improved-unarmed-strike-does/56568#56568)

Comment: [I made a chatroom, if you want.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42815/deflect-attack-discussion)

Comment: Homebrew feat needs amendment to text, either allowing or disallowing this interaction. Homebrew really is a constant wip

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, the two feats are not actually interacting directly.
*Deflect Attack* simply grants extra chances for an Attack of Opportunity.
*Evasive Reflexes* simply grants you an alternate option to resolve a chance to make an AoO.

**However**, *Deflect Attack* has specific clauses detailing how you may use your AoO when an opponent attacks you armed or unarmed. With that detail, we follow the "specific beats general" ruling, and any AoO granted by *Deflect Attack* must be used to make a counterattack.

Regarding the question in the title, and the "general" question:
Yes, a feat can do that, if that is what the feat specifies that it does.

For instance, one of **Elusive Target**'s options is "*Negate Power Attack*": after designating a Dodge target (the Dodge feat), if that target attempts to make a power attack against you they gain no bonus on the damage roll but still take the penalty on attack.

---

I managed to read the requirement for how *Deflect Attack* allows you to use your AoO like 3 times, and I still somehow managed to not actually process it until Simon pointed it out to me specifically. Thanks for catching that one!