# Do miss chances stack?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dnd-3e

Say a paranoid magic user has Blurring bracers of armor, Mirror Image, Blink, Invisibility, Wings of Cover, and Etherealness going. How to calculate the miss chances versus a normal attack, magic attack, force attack, and so forth?

Answer (score 9):

### Don't stack miss chances; instead use the highest miss chance that affects an incoming effect

The *Rules Compendium* says, "If a creature receives miss chances from multiple sources, such as from being incorporeal and having concealment, only the highest miss chance applies" (32).

#### Suspicious of the *Rules Compendium*?

The *Rules Compendium*—by here expanding yet not contradicting the core rules—, [in this case](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/37466/8610) serves its function as the *Player's Handbook* concerns itself with miss chances due exclusively to [concealment](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/combatModifiers.html#concealment) (e.g. "Multiple concealment conditions (such as a defender in a fog and under the effect of a [*blur*](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/spellsAtoB.html#blur) spell) do not stack" (*PH* 152)).

Comment: The Compendium had a lot of novel interpretations. Do you recall if that's supported by the SRD?

Comment: @fectin The core rules concern themselves with miss chances exclusively due to concealment ("Multiple concealment conditions (such as a defender in a fog and under the effect of a *blur* spell) do not stack" (*PH* 152)). The *Rules Compendium* expands but doesn't contradict those rules.

Comment: The *Player's Handbook* (2000) says, "Do not add the miss chances together" (133), which is much easier but also out of context and pre-*3.5* revision. Also, the *PH*  quotation above is hilarious  in some electronic versions of the *PH* (a product of OCR misinterpretation or mischief I know not) but the hilarity is absent in print versions.