# Do Blink, Blur, normal concealment & Displacement stack?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, stacking, concealment

Just what the title says, Do Blink, Blur, normal concealment & Displacement stack? Do any of them stack? Do all of them stack? Which ones, if any?

Comment: While the question very well may be *Can a creature simultaneous be the subject of all of these spells?*, I think the actual root of the question is identical to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/84458/8610). If that's inaccurate, please edit the question to clarify it further. If that's accurate, say so and this question'll be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: Oh dear, yes it indeed appears that my question is a duplicate. My bad. I searched before posting this question just in case but I must've been too specific in my wording.

Comment: Not even a thing. I hope the linked question and its answers were useful.