# Can a creature activate its Gaze attack along with a Full Attack with Natural Weapons?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters, natural-weapon

The Universal Monster Rule [Gaze](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Gaze-Su-) indicates:

> A creature with a gaze attack can actively gaze as an attack action by choosing a target within range.

Being an 'attack action' (not a Standard Action), can this be used with a creature's Natural Attacks as part of a Full Attack?

Comment: [Related for *3.5e*.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/100841/8610)

Comment: [Related for other kinds of attacks](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/102943/extraordinary-abilities-and-full-attack-actions/102948#102948)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the [attack action](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Standard-Action) and *an attack* are different things.

From the combat rules:

> Attack Action: An attack action is a type of **standard action**. Some combat options can modify only this specific sort of action.

This means that directing the *Gaze* ability is a *standard action*. And that such creature could effectively attempt to affect a target with their *gaze* twice in a single round, as illustrated on [this answer from 3.5 regarding gaze attacks](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/100841/what-happens-when-a-creature-with-two-gaze-attacks-focuses-its-gaze).

Comment: Good reference. I'm going to see if there's a contending answer before accepting.